# Change Style when toggle between data in Google Heatmap

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I'm using this code to toggle between two different heatmaps:

[Toggle between data in Google Heat Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847944/toggle-between-data-in-google-heat-map/40706352)

Is it possible to give each taxidata its own style, `e.g. two different gradients?`

And is it possible to tell `e.g.`

```
<button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
```

which taxidata is selected?`

Im using the following code:

```
<script>
window.onerror = function(){return true;}
  var map = null;
  var heatmap = null;
  var heatmap2 = null;
  var pointArray = null;
  var pointArray2 = null;
  var firstData = true;

  var taxiData = [
    <?
        foreach ($UserLocationHistory as $item) {
            echo "new google.maps.LatLng(" .$item['UserPosLat'] . ", " .$item['UserPosLong'] . "),";
        }

    ?>
  ]; 

var taxiData2 = [];
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng('48.139581, 11.579585'),
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);
    pointArray2 = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData2);

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: pointArray,
        radius: 25,
        opacity: 0.7,
    })

    heatmap.setMap(map);
    heatmap2.setMap(map);
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id="panel">
    <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()" class="btn btn-info">Anzeige wechseln</button>
  </div>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:450px; width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.  What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Regarding the switch of the style I've tried to adda second Heatmap Definition: "heatmap2 = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({ data: pointArray2.... But that broke the script. Regarding the selection of which taxidata: nothing. I'm a Beginner and not so firm with Javascript

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question that demonstrates the issue ([edit] your question)

Comment: related question: [Heat map data is not displaying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796490/heat-map-data-is-not-displaying)

Comment: There is no `toggleHeatmap()` function in the posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `toggleHeatmap()` function (basically copied and pasted from the question you reference, but including the gradient from that function) works for me:

```
function toggleHeatmap() {
  if (firstData) {
    heatmap.setData(pointArray2);
    firstData = false;
  } else {
    heatmap.setData(pointArray);
    firstData = true;
  }
    var gradient = [
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
    'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
    'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
    'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
  ]
  heatmap.setOptions({
    gradient: heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x1g6L8nu/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.139581, 11.579585),
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);
  pointArray2 = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData2);

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: pointArray,
    radius: 25,
    opacity: 0.7,
  })
  heatmap.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function toggleHeatmap() {
  if (firstData) {
    heatmap.setData(pointArray2);
    firstData = false;
  } else {
    heatmap.setData(pointArray);
    firstData = true;
  }
  var gradient = [
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
    'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
    'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
    'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
  ]
  heatmap.setOptions({
    gradient: heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient
  });
}

var map = null;
var heatmap = null;
var heatmap2 = null;
var pointArray = null;
var pointArray2 = null;
var firstData = true;

var taxiData = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.239581, 11.579585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.139581, 11.679585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.339581, 11.779585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.139581, 11.879585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.239581, 11.479585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.139581, 11.379585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.239581, 11.279585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.139581, 11.179585),

];

var taxiData2 = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.139581, 11.579585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.239581, 11.679585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.139581, 11.779585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.339581, 11.879585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.139581, 11.479585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.239581, 11.379585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.139581, 11.279585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.239581, 11.179585),
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization"></script>
<div>
  <div id="panel">
    <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()" class="btn btn-info">Anzeige wechseln</button>
  </div>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:450px; width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```